# Powershell script to parse CSV to get the file ownership

Tags: powershell

I need to get the owner of files which I have the list in .CSV file as the absolute folder path so that I add the result in secondary column which list the owner of the files.

Thanks in advance.

The first column of the CSV:

```
G:\Directory1\file1.zip
H:\Directory3\file4.docx
.
.
.
F:\Directory99\file234324.bat
```

The second column is none, but I'd like it to be:

```
Username1
Username2
.
.
.
Username99
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just have a line-separated list of files, it's not a csv file - it's just a text file.

You could check if each file exist and use [`Get-Acl`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849802.aspx) to provide the ownership information:

```
$files = Get-Content C:\path\to\list.csv
$fileowners = @()
foreach ($file in $files)
{
  if(Test-Path $file -pathType leaf)
  {
    $owner = (Get-Acl $file).Owner
  }
  else
  {
    $owner = "!File not found"
  }
  $fileowner = @{"File"=$file;"Owner"=$owner}
  $fileowners += $fileowner
}
$fileowners | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\path\to\final.csv
```

Comment: +1 Nice job checking for the file's existence first.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, but somehow I got this error: Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Add'. +   $fileowners.Add <<<< ($fileowner)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Add:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: My bad, updated

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Select-Object` and a [calculated property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to generate the CSV.

Note that your question indicates there is no header in the source CSV file. I'm adding the headings of "File" and "Owner" to the output.

```
Import-Csv input.csv -Header "File"  |
     Select-Object File, @{ Name = "Owner"; Expression = { ( Get-Acl( Get-Item $_.File ) ).Owner } } |
        Export-Csv -Path output.csv
```